# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu=0$ imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f_n-f|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measurable space,$g_n,g,f_n,f\in L^1(X,R)$,if $|g_n(x)|\leq f_n(x)$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$ pointwise,if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu=0,$$does that imply
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f_n-f|=0$$

Comment: @avid19 I deleted my comment -- trying to make it more precise made it clear (for instance, as it is the OP doesn't specify the last limit it pointwise for $x$). What are the counterexamples for a.e. convergence? (I'm forgetting quite a lot)

Comment: The best you can do in general (without more knowledge about the $f_n$) is that a subsequence of the $f_n$ converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.

Answer (score 5):

No. Let $X=[0,1]$ with Borel sets and standard Lebesgue measure. Consider the sequence of indicator functions:

$$\Bbb{1}_{[0,1/2]},\Bbb{1}_{[1/2,1]},\Bbb{1}_{[0,1/3]},...$$

This is a traveling bump and clearly $\int_{[0,1]} f_n(x) dx\to 0$, but each point goes back and forth between $0$ and $1$. So this converges NOWHERE but converges in $L^1$.

As a side note, $(X, M, \mu)$ is a measure space. A measurable space is without the actual measure.

**Edit** I don't understand your edit. Just let $g_n(x)=0$. $g_n(x)$ won't help anything.

Comment: would that have a.e. convergence?

Comment: @89085731 As I explicitly said, it converges nowhere.

Comment: what if $|g_n(x)|<f_n(x)$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$,does that imply  $f_n\rightarrow f$

Comment: @89085731 What do you mean by $g_n \to g$?

Comment: pointwise convergent

Comment: @89085731 Then that is blatantly false. Think about it for 10 seconds and I'm sure you'll find an example.

Comment: I mean if it is true under the condition $g_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$

Comment: @89085731 You should probably state your question clearly and in a new question. And then, how I understand it, it is plainly false too.

Comment: sorry for that, I have edited the question

Comment: sorry for that. what if $g_n\neq 0$, I couldn't think out a nontrivial example

Comment: @89085731 You can't keep changing the question. What is this for? What do you want?

Comment: actually I want to prove the dominated convergence theorem, but instead of $|g_n(x)| \leq f$, we have the condition above. So I am wondering if I can prove $f_n(x)\rightarrow f$ pointwise

Comment: @89085731 If you want a proof of dominated convergence, just ask (or better yet, search) for one. Your last one is not true as well. Just add $1$ to $g_n$ and $f_n$.

Comment: ok thanks. Sorry for keep editing